# Write or token create operations are not allowed in procedure using cypher projection

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

When calling a procedure using an evaluated inner query ([cypher projection](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/projected-graph-model/cypher-projection/))which would be creating an node or edge a forbidden error is thrown for the admin user. It is possible to run the query outside the procedure.

Maybe it is something of an configuration issue?

I am trying to run a query using the timetree procedure of GraphAware and the LabelPropagation of Neo4j. But I've been able to get the forbidden error using a much simpler query. I am using Neo4j Desktop. I have tried giving the admin all the possible roles.

For example

```
call apoc.cypher.run("create (n:Test) return n",{}) yield value return *
```

Or another example:

```
CALL algo.labelPropagation.stream(
    'CALL ga.timetree.events.range({start: 1480896000000, end: 1520294400000}) YIELD node RETURN id(node) AS id',
    'MATCH (c1:Case)-[r:NARROWER_THAN]->(c2:Case) RETURN id(c1) AS source, id(c2) as target, r.score AS weight', 
    { graph:'cypher'}
)YIELD nodeId, label
with label as lpa, collect(nodeId) as ids, count(nodeId) as c  
where c > 2
return lpa, c, ids  
order by c desc
```

These are the errors for the first and second example:

`Neo.ClientError.Security.Forbidden: Token create operations are not allowed for user 'neo4j' with roles [admin,architect,editor,publisher,reader] restricted to READ.`

`Neo.ClientError.Security.Forbidden: Write operations are not allowed for user 'neo4j' with roles [admin,architect,editor,publisher,reader] restricted to READ.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure `apoc.cypher.run` can only execute *read queries*. Creating/updating/deleting nodes is not allowed with it.

Comment: nmervaillie: I gave that one as a simplified example, maybe not the best idead. In reality I am using the labelPropagation in combination with timetree (added it to my original question). How could I find out which procedures are allowed to execute write queries?

Comment: You can check it out using this query : `CALL dbms.procedures() YIELD name, mode RETURN name, mode`. In this case, the `algo.labelPropagation.stream` procedure has mode `DEFAULT` (`READ`), and cannot invoke `ga.timetree.events.range` which has `WRITE` mode

Comment: Thank you for for the explanation. I will create a new question about how I can call a cypher projection supporting procedure with input from another procedure (or query) which can write.